# JSON fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (llbd)

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, xcode7

I'm having this issue when user is trying to log in

```
let success:NSInteger = jsonData!.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger
```

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(llbd)**

I have no idea how to unwrap this thing, I've been stuck for weeks :(, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why you are not using if let statement or gaurd statement, to unwrap optional value ?

Comment: @AjayKumar thanks a lot for your reply, I'm new into iOS and Swift dev, can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: If you can post more code, it would be easy to help, And what's your jsonData

Comment: @AjayKumar `let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary` does that help ?

Comment: Just check this, Before executing above line which you have posted, just try printing your jasonData, Whether you have value there or its nil ?

Comment: This is the jsonData I'm getting:

`2016-01-15 04:10:59.600 Easy Parking[41923:1738773] Response ==> [{"cod":"1","sess":"647b11c75575ac66c5877a62626aa3a7","nombre":"<"}]
(lldb) `

Comment: Btw I'm basing my project with this guide [link](https://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2015/07/ios-login-signup-screen-tutorial-swift-2-xcode-7-ios-9-json/)

Comment: So you can see that there is no key called *success* in your JsonData, so it will surely crash.

Comment: Yeah !!! I realize of that, hehehe, but keeps throwing the same error

Comment: please add your relevant code in description rather than on comments

Answer (score 1):

You need check the `jsonData!.valueForKey("success")` value. It's nil. Nil can't convert to Int. Or you can do like this:

```
let success = jsonData!.valueForKey("success") as? NSInteger
```

Xcode lldb may have some issue for pod command. I debug value of var by  write "print(...)" in my code.
Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. It seems the problem is before this statement, I did as you suggested but keep throwing the same error.

Comment: BTW, this is the guide I'm basing my project [link](https://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2015/07/ios-login-signup-screen-tutorial-swift-2-xcode-7-ios-9-json/)

Comment: whether value of  `jsonData`  is nill ?

Comment: you must always check the value of var  type. You can't convert nil to any other no optional var. eg : `let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary`. if `urlData` is nil . `urlData!` will throw a error. symbol `!` says the value of urlData must not  be nil